# Executar dinamicamente método de classe model a partir de uma requisição ajax para o controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, mvc, eval

Estou criando uma funcionalidade em meu sistema para recarregamento de componentes dinamicamente, de forma que sejam executadas consultas que estão alocadas em classes da camada de modelo, através de requisições AJAX. Porém, como utilizo o padrão MVC a partir do framework CodeIgniter, toda requisição ou execução deve partir de uma classe de controle, logo, não posso executar as consultas diretamente através da classe model onde a mesma se encontra.

Alguém saberia me informar uma ferramenta ou técnica que facilitaria este meu trabalho? Sendo possível executar as consultas que estão no model de maneira segura diretamente a partir da requisição AJAX, sem passar no controller? Ou em caso negativo, existe alguma ferramenta ou função que me permitiria executar dinamicamente os métodos das classes model a partir de um controller para esta função?

Apenas para efeito de testes, comecei a desenvolver um método em um controller específico para executar dinamicamente a classe e o método solicitado por parâmetro via requisição (http ou ajax), porém esta função será muito trabalhosa se for utilizá-la em ambiente de produção, já que tenho que definir parâmetros e tratá-los de acordo com o tipo ao concatenar na string, e pior, como seriam passados via url:

```
public function requestJson($classe, $metodo, $parametros = array()) {

echo "Executando o método <i>{$metodo}</i> a classe <i>{$classe}</i>:<br>";

$str = '$class = new ' . $classe . '();'
                . '$class->' . $metodo . '();';

        return eval($str);
}
```

Comment: A ideia do MVC é todas as requisições passarem por algum controller. O Codeigniter já faz muita mágica mapeando os controllers com as rotas da URL. O mais correto é você fazer as chamadas do model no seu controller, ou simplesmente abandonar o MVC.

Answer (score 1):

O mais simples é chamar diretamente o  metodo do model

```
public function requestJson($classe, $metodo, $parametros = array()) {


$var =  "Executando o método <i>{$metodo}</i> a classe <i>{$classe}</i>:<br>";

    return json_encode($this->nome_do_model->requestJson($classe, $metodo, $parametros));
}
```

E no Model colocar o retorno de texto

```
public function requestJson($classe, $metodo, $parametros){
//executa os metodos e retorna para o controller
return "Executando o método <i>{$metodo}</i> a classe <i>{$classe}</i>:<br>";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

O que costumo fazer quando faço uma requisição Ajax é fazer a chamada no controller, o controller requisita os dados, com isso jogo numa view ou em um json para retornar os dados para a requisição ajax.

exemplo do html:

```
<a href="#" id="exemploAjax">Link Ajax</a>
<div id="respostaAjax"></div>
```

exemplo do js:

```
$('a#exemploAjax').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'meu_controller/meu_metodo',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(resp)  {

            var resp = $.parseJSON(resp);

            if (resp.success === true) {
                $('#respostaAjax').html(resp.msg);
            }
            else {
                alert(resp.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

exemplo do controller:

```
class Meu_controller extends MY_Controller {

    public function meu_metodo()
    {
        $this->load->model('meu_model_m');
        $dados['items'] = $this->meu_model_m->get_items();

        $this->load->view('minha_view', $dados);
    }

}
```

exemplo do model:

```
class Meu_model_m extends MY_Model {

    public function get_items()
    {
        $query = $this->db
            ->select('nome')
            ->get('tabela_items');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        }

        return array();
    }

}
```

exemplo da view:

```
<h1>Exemplo Ajax - Lista Items</h1>
<?php
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo '<li>';
    echo $item->nome;
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Marcelo, este método que você demonstrou é necessário algum framework não ?

Comment: Sim, Codeigniter que foi em relação a pergunta dele!